# PostgreSQL pgAgent's job can't work

Tags: postgresql, pgagent

When I use postgres, the job works, but when I use ydz2, the job doesn't work:

> Couldn't get a connection to the database

Both of them are my local database.

**Job Step**

[image]

**Job Step Statistics**

[image]

Where should I configure it?

Thank you.

Comment: hey @ThomasFlinkow I would also normally downvote such a question, but considering it concerns pgAgent, it is rather helpful to show some screenshots. +1 for the thorough evaluation :-)

Comment: @JimJones you're right, I removed the downvote. The pictures do actually help in this case. Also, when I saw the post in review, the pictures didn't show, but rather they were links only.

Answer (score 2):

It seems pgagent cannot connect to the database, which might be because you didn't provide the required credentials. Make sure your **[.pgpass](https://www.pgadmin.org/docs/pgadmin4/dev/using_pgagent.html)** file is properly configured.

Assuming you're using the user `postgres` for pgAgent and that you have installed the extension in the database `postgres`:

```
$ sudo su - postgres
$ cd ~
$ nano .pgpass
```

Insert the following text and save the document:

```
localhost:5432:*:postgres:[postgres_password]
```

This line basically tells the database connection to use the given password for the user `postgres` to connect to any (`*`) database on the server `localhost` listening on the port `5432`.

Once you're done with the .pgpass, give the file the proper permissions:

```
$ chmod 0600 .pgpass
```

You might need to restart pgAgent (not sure if it's necessary):

```
$ pgagent hostaddr=localhost dbname=postgres user=postgres
```